# Cannot get info from post method in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I have made super simple code for the sole purpose of receiving data from the client.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var PORT = 80;

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send('<form action="/" method="post"> <input type="text"name="firstname" value="Mickey"><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body.firstname);
res.send('POST request to the homepage');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Listening on port "+PORT));
```

That is it. but when I run it it says that req.body.firstname is undefined. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this using node.js or another JS library? If so include it in the tag.

Comment: `app.get('/', ...)` should likely return a whole web page, not just a form unless that request is design only for an ajax call, not for the browser.  And, if that's the case, then you probably have a CORS issue too.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a space in here:`<input type="text"name="firstname"` before the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

To parse form data, you'll have to use the [`bodyParser.urlencoded`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) middleware.

Add the following to your code, before you handle the POST request:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```